# Popup messages for validation

Tags: java, swing, popup

I'd like to have some small popup messages appear under text fields to indicate if inputted information is incorrect like on Spring/Eclipse RCP. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you link to a picture or description or, better, both?

Comment: @Trashgod: Please have a look at "6. Customer Validations and ControlDecoration" on this article: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO there are at least two ways to achieve that. You can use [JGlassPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) or [JXLayer framework](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2008/06/the_new_jxlayer.html). The basic idea to draw your popup messages on the transparent layer "above" your text fields.

I used the JXLayer framework because I felt it gave me a greater flexibility in what I could do.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably take a look at [JGoodies Validation](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html) open source library. It does what you want and much more. It is probably better than reinventing the wheel.