# How to turn off window manager urgency hints for a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JFrame` that is basically nothing more than a few `JProgressBar`s for a data conversion program that takes several hours to complete.  My problem is that the window manager urgency hint gets activated every time I update a progress bar, which is really annoying to have in the corner of my eye all day.  I do still want it in my taskbar to be able to check it quickly, so changing it to a `JDialog` doesn't help.  How can I turn off the urgency hints?

If it helps, the program actually runs on Windows 7, java version 1.7.0, although I do a lot of debugging with mock data on a Linux box, so cross-platform solutions are preferred but not critical.

Comment: Ironically, on my last project, using pygtk, I spent some effort trying to turn the urgency hints _on_.

Comment: Platform-dependent solution (i.e. Windows OS) - http://superuser.com/questions/316879/how-can-i-disable-flashing-icons-on-windows-7-taskbar. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes @mre, except for only disabled for one application.  Missing notifications from other apps would be worse than the false positives from this one.

Answer (score 1):

maybe nothing complicated, standards

1) setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

2) there no reason to dispay the JFrame, calling for setVisible(true) see point 5th.

3) [System Tray Functionality in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/)

4) you have to add JPopupMenu to the TrayIcon

5) if some events occured then

- [TrayIcon#displayMessage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType%29) here you can notify for blablabla as "Aplication started", "for any Aplications Events", or whatever
- or by using setVisible(true) display JFrame, but there would be better to search for [JFrame#getExtendedState](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getExtendedState%28%29), reason just flashing with [JFrame#ICONIFIED](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) in the TaskBar

Comment: You're saying to put the program's icon in the system tray instead of the task bar?

Comment: @Karl Bielefeldt, sure that is very sillent mode, are  you ever disturbanced some of notification for example update from Antivirus, but there is another way in the case if you pass JFrame as parent for JDialog, JWindow, JOptionPane, then it will be same as (for endUser) as TrayIcon#displayMessage, just you have to calculate with Toolbar's HIEGHT (toolbar from Native OS), since workaround would be little bit harder, but not it be impossible ...

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138511/how-to-display-a-temporary-baloon-tooltip-during-input-validation